# MySql join query

Tags: mysql, join

want to join two tables and produce a result like ..ie.,

```
Table : 1
-------------------------------
Text val1 val2 val3 val4
-------------------------------
Test  96  1  4 0
Test  96  3  4 0
Test  96  5  4 0
Test  96  7  4 0
Test  96  9  4 0
Test  96  11 4 0
Test  96  13 4 0
Test  96  15 4 0
Test  87  7  6 1
Test1 87  7  6 1
Test1 95  5  4 0
Test1 95  13 4 0
Test2 109 15 6 0
Test3 109 15 5 0
Test4 109 15 4 0
Test5 109 15 3 0
Test6 107 0  7 0
Test7 107 0  6 0
Test8 107 0  5 0
Test9 107 0  4 0

Table : 2
-------------------------------
ID  val1 val2 val3 val4
-------------------------------
10   96 1  4 0
10   96 3  4 0
10   96 5  4 0
10   96 7  4 0
10   96 9  4 0
10   96 11 4 0
10   96 13 4 0
10   96 15 4 0
10   87 7  6 1
11   87 7  6 1
11   95 5  4 0
11   95 13 4 0
12  109 15 6 0
13  109 15 5 0
14  109 15 4 0
15  109 15 3 0
16  107 0  7 0
17  107 0  6 0
18  107 0  4 0

Output Table
-------------------------------
Text ID  val1 val2 val3 val4
-------------------------------
Test  10   96 1  4 0
Test  10   96 3  4 0
Test  10   96 5  4 0
Test  10   96 7  4 0
Test  10   96 9  4 0
Test  10   96 11 4 0
Test  10   96 13 4 0
Test  10   96 15 4 0
Test  10   87 7  6 1
Test1 11   87 7  6 1
Test1 11   95 5  4 0
Test1 11   95 13 4 0
Test2 12  109 15 6 0
Test3 13  109 15 5 0
Test4 14  109 15 4 0
Test5 15  109 15 3 0
Test6 16  107 0  7 0
Test7 17  107 0  6 0
Test8 18  107 0  4 0
```

Kindly help me wih select query for the same.

Comment: It's a trivial `JOIN` query. What have you tried, and what problem did you have with it? We're not here to do your work for you, we're here to help you fix your code.

Comment: cool, am new to this, i tried few simple join query.

Comment: Post what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.TEXT
     , table2.id
     , table1.val1
     , table1.val2
     , table1.val3,table1.val4

  from table1 
  join table2 
    on table1.val1 = table2.val 
   and table1.val2 = table2.val2 
   and table1.val3 = table2.val3
   and table1.val4 = table2.val4
```

Comment: column has beeb added

Comment: Tried the same got follwing result

Comment: Test 10 96 1 4 0
Test 10 96 3 4 0
Test 10 96 5 4 0
Test 10 96 7 4 0
Test 10 96 9 4 0
Test 10 96 11 4 0
Test 10 96 13 4 0
Test 10 96 15 4 0
Test1 10 87 7 6 1
Test 10 87 7 6 1
Test1 11 87 7 6 1
Test 11 87 7 6 1
Test1 11 95 5 4 0
Test1 11 95 13 4 0
Test2 12 109 15 6 0
Test3 13 109 15 5 0
Test4 14 109 15 4 0
Test5 15 109 15 3 0
Test6 16 107 0 7 0
Test7 17 107 0 6 0
Test9 18 107 0 4 0

Comment: whats the difference in expected and this result ?

Comment: Test & Test1 are having two entries of Test1 10 87 7 6 1 Test 10 87 7 6 1

Comment: how to avoid the same. Result should be same posted above

Comment: Output Table
-------------------------------
Text ID  val1 val2 val3 val4
-------------------------------
Test  10   96 1  4 0
Test  10   96 3  4 0
Test  10   96 5  4 0
Test  10   96 7  4 0
Test  10   96 9  4 0
Test  10   96 11 4 0
Test  10   96 13 4 0
Test  10   96 15 4 0
Test  10   87 7  6 1
Test1 11   87 7  6 1
Test1 11   95 5  4 0
Test1 11   95 13 4 0
Test2 12  109 15 6 0
Test3 13  109 15 5 0
Test4 14  109 15 4 0
Test5 15  109 15 3 0
Test6 16  107 0  7 0
Test7 17  107 0  6 0
Test8 18  107 0  4 0

Answer (score -2):

```
select table1.Text,table2.Id,table1.val1,table1.val2,table1.val3,table1.val4 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.val1 = table2.val1 and table1.val2 = table2.val2 and table1.val3 = table2.val3 and table1.val4 = table2.val4
```

Comment: You need to join on all the `valX` columns, not just `val1`.

Comment: Ok you can add other by adding and

Comment: did the same. Worked fine, but for test & test1 entries got two additional rows.

Comment: Test 10 96 1 4 0
Test 10 96 3 4 0
Test 10 96 5 4 0
Test 10 96 7 4 0
Test 10 96 9 4 0
Test 10 96 11 4 0
Test 10 96 13 4 0
Test 10 96 15 4 0
Test1 10 87 7 6 1
Test 10 87 7 6 1
Test1 11 87 7 6 1
Test 11 87 7 6 1
Test1 11 95 5 4 0
Test1 11 95 13 4 0
Test2 12 109 15 6 0
Test3 13 109 15 5 0
Test4 14 109 15 4 0
Test5 15 109 15 3 0
Test6 16 107 0 7 0
Test7 17 107 0 6 0
Test9 18 107 0 4 0

Comment: Refer above for desired output

Comment: Consider adding some extra information to your post, and not only the code. Explain how you came to this solution for example.